# jqxgrid row selection on mouse click nor working

Tags: php, jqxgrid

Im using jqwidjets jqxgrif for one of my project.
In grid i want select a row and edit it in another page(href link).the EDIT link in outside the grid.

currently im using following code to row select.but its only working for keyboard navigation not for mouse select.how do i enable mouse select and pass row index to outside edit link onclick event.

```
    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
        {   width : '100%',
            source: dataadapter,
            selectionmode: 'singlerow',
            altrows: true,
            theme: theme,
            filterable: true,
            autoheight: true,
            pageable: true,
            columnsresize: true,
            //virtualmode: true,
            pagesizeoptions: ['10', '15', '20'],
            pagesize:20,
            sortable: true,

            ready: function () {
                           //$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('sortby', 'ObjectId', 'asc');
                            //$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('selectionmode', 'singlerow');
                           $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('selectrow', 0);
                       },


            rendergridrows: function () {
                return dataadapter.records;
            },
            columns: [
```

Comment: i wonder who names this framework "jqwidjets jqxgrif"... sounds like a cat walking on keyboard random typing to me.

Comment: :) the framework is jqwidgets and the component is jqxgrid :) There's a typo in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following for getting the click and keyboard, hopefully this helps.

```
$('#jqxgrid').bind('rowselect', function(event)  {
  var current_index = event.args.rowindex;
  var datarow = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getrowdata', current_index);

  // Use datarow for display of data in div outside of grid
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#jqxgrid").bind('rowselect', function (event) {                
});
```